# program crashes at wglmakecurrent

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, mfc

I am using opengl in a MFC application in visual studio 2008.
and there my project crashes at  wglmakecurrent saying:

> Access violation reading location

This happens only for a certain case so this is probably not a driver issue. And also I have checked in another machine where the same error occurs.

The error occurs at wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC,m_hRC) in the following function:

> void CCETIGLView::Convert2D(CPoint win, GLdouble * objx, 
>                                        GLdouble * objy, GLdouble * objz)
>   {
>   if((m_hDC) && (m_hRC))
>   {
>
> wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC,m_hRC);
>       }

The parameters are of following types:

> HGLRC m_hRC;
>
> HDC m_hDC;

Tthey are obtained from a glview class which is a child class of cview.

It returns 0 for GetLastError() when I check wglMakeCurrent function.
This happens when rendering a certain option and other options work fine.

I am using single thread therefore multi threading issue also does not count.

Comment: There is not enough information provided to answer this question. Where are you calling this function? What are those parameters and how did you create them? And so forth. You haven't said anything beyond, "My code crashes when running this line."

Comment: We're not going to play 20 questions, where I ask a question, and you answer with the minimum possible information, then I ask a follow-up, and you answer with the minimum possible info for that. You need to provide *full information*, preferably in the form of actual *source code*, that provides us with 100% of what we would need to resolve this issue. And you need to put this in your question, not a comment.

Comment: Updated the question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

This test

> if((m_hDC) && (m_hRC))

only makes sense if it is made sure that m_hDC and m_hRC are initialized to 0 upon class creation, so that one can actually tell, that they're initialized. Probably you're not doing this, so those variables contain non-zero garbage and hence are misinterpreted as being initialized with valid handles.

Add constant initialization to the constructor

```
CCETIGLView::CCETIGLView() :
    m_hDC(0), m_hRC(0)
{
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @datenwolf. I have already assigned them to 0, but still the same error. They pass the if condition as well. but m_hDC is shown as ,"error: expression can't be evaluated." and m_hRC is shown as, "unused, 0" in the debug mode. Any idea? thanks again.